# Polynomial Question

Tags: polynomials, discrete-mathematics, algorithms

Find polynomials $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ such that $A(x)P(x) + B(x)Q(x) = x + 1$ for all $x$ where $P(x) = x^4 - 1$ and $Q(x) = x^3 + x^2$. I'm stumped on this question. I know that I'm supposed to apply the extended version of Euclid's algorithm for polynomials but I'm unsure of how to do that. I thought about trying to create some kind of linear system but guessing arbitrary coefficients but that wouldn't work as $A$ and $B$ don't have fixed degrees.

Comment: Also, I know that you can divide through by $x + 1$ to get one on the right side. I think that's important.

Comment: How would you do it for integers?  eg. find integers $A$ and $B$ such that $A\cdot P + B\cdot Q = 3$ where $P=15$ and $Q = 12$?

Comment: Both $P$ and $Q$ are divisible by $x+1$ so divide through to make the process easier. This trick won't always work in general though.

Comment: Are we allowed to divide through by $x + 1$ since the statement wouldn't hold hold $x = -1$ (dividing by zero)?

Comment: Well if you want to get really fussy, yeah, the conclusion you reach will only hold for all the points where $x≠-1$, but later on you'll be able to fix the "hole"

Comment: No, the statement already trivially holds for $x=-1$, for any $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Could anyone maybe show the steps? I'm just confused about the algebra at this point -- I understand the use of the algorithm.

Comment: @Berci Yeah, that's the argument you use to "fill the hole"

Answer (score 2):

By using Extended Euclidean Algorithm,

$$\begin{align}
x^4-1 =& \left(x^3+x^2\right)(x-1) +x^2-1\\
x^3+x^2 =& \left(x^2-1\right)(x+1) + x+1\\
x^2-1 =& \left(x+1\right)(x-1) + 0
\end{align}$$

And so $x+1$ is the GCD of $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$. Now, we substitute previous remainders to the second-to-last line:

$$\begin{align}
x+1 =& \left(x^3+x^2\right) - \left(x^2-1\right)(x+1)\\
=& \left(x^3+x^2\right) - \left[\left(x^4-1\right) - \left(x^3+x^2\right)(x-1)\right](x+1)\\
=& \left(x^3+x^2\right)\left[1+(x-1)(x+1)\right] - \left(x^4-1\right)(x+1)\\
=& \left(-x-1\right)\left(x^4-1\right) + x^2\left(x^3+x^2\right)\\
\end{align}$$

Therefore, $A(x) = -x-1$ and $B(x)=x^2$ is a pair of solution.

Answer (score 0):

We have $P=(x^4-1)=(x+1)(x-1)(x^2+1)$ and $Q=(x+1)x^2$.

We can divide through by the common factor $(x+1)$, getting $Q_1={\bf x^2}$ and $P_1=(x-1)(x^2+1)=(x-1){\bf x^2}+(x-1)=(x-1)Q_1+\,{\bf (x-1)}$.  $\ \ (1)$

Now let's continue the division: ${\bf x^2}=(x+1){\bf (x-1)}\,+1$.

Writing back $(x-1)$ from $\,(1)$, we have 
$$Q_1=(x+1)\,{\it (P_1 - (x-1)Q_1)} \  +1$$
And from this, we can express $1$ as linear combination of $P_1$ and $Q_1$ with polynomial coefficients.