# Eucledian polynomial prooving

Tags: polynomials

If $C(x)=x^4−1$ and $D(x)=x^3+x^2$

How do I go about proving that there are no polynomials $C(x)$ and $D(x)$ such that $C(x)P(x) +D(x)Q(x) = 1$ for all $x$.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/509402/polynomial-question/509429

Answer (score 3):

Find a common factor of $C(x)$ and $D(x)$, and you can see you can factorise the left hand side of $C(x)P(x) +D(x)Q(x)=1$. However, the right hand side does not have this factor, which contradicts that equation.